# Gulp Scss issue

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I am using this gulp scss plugin.
https://github.com/Forumouth/gulp-scss

And I created my gulp task like this.

```
var scss = require("gulp-scss");

gulp.task("scss", function () {
  gulp.src(
    "assets/stylesheets/hauls.scss"
  ).pipe(scss(
    {"bundleExec": true}
  )).pipe(gulp.dest("assets/stylesheets/hauls.css"));
});
```

But when I run "gulp scss" I get this error message.

```
[10:19:32] Starting 'scss'...
[10:19:32] Finished 'scss' after 15 ms
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

and when I run "scss" command manually it works.

```
scss assets/stylesheets/hauls.scss assets/stylesheets/hauls.css
```

I have no idea what this error means.
I installed ruby as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator of the plugin says [it's obsolete and there's no reason to use his buggy plugin anymore](https://github.com/Forumouth/gulp-scss#note-this-script-is-obsolete). Use [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) instead.